# How high can manned subsonic planes go?

Tags: supersonic, high-altitude

What is the maximum altitude a manned plane that flies subsonically can reach? Subsonic airplanes can't go as high as super- and hypersonic ones of course, so record holders are the latter ones. But ironically, the altitude record for leveled flight is set by the subsonic NASA Helios propeller aircraft at ~97,000 ft. However that's an uncrewed and weird-looking one. Can manned airplanes that fly subsonically go above the Armstrong line (60-63,000 ft) and higher (either in leveled or in parabolic flight), considering realistic fuel limitations? How high can subsonic airplanes go compared to supersonic ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

76,000 feet.  [Airbus Perlan Mission II glider](https://www.airbus.com/en/newsroom/press-releases/2018-09-airbus-perlan-mission-ii-glider-soars-to-76000-feet-to-break-own), Sept 2, 2018.  (If Airbus keeps changing their press releases' URLs, see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windward_Performance_Perlan_II).)

The U-2 has a higher service ceiling, 80,000 feet, but it hasn't reached that.
(Perlan II's service ceiling is 90,000 feet.)

Comment: But that's a glider, how did it get into the air in the first place? Do the Perlan gliders launch on winches?

Comment: @Giovanni a glider is a plane, and it is both manned and subsonic, thus fulfilling all your criterias set in the question, no?

Comment: Look up the U2.

Comment: @Federico Not if another plane brought it to or close to that altitude. I'd count it only if the glider was released at low altitude or launched on a winch.

Comment: @Giovanni but you did not specify as much in the question

Comment: @Federico If another plane brought it up there, I'd count the other plane's flight (if it's subsonic). But you're right in that I rather meant jet planes. Still, interesting. Perhaps I'll edit my question sometime to set the focus on jets.

Comment: @Giovanni: If it was brought to that altitude by another plane, then that plane could obviously fly to that altitude.  But it wasn't: it's a sailplane: it's released at low altitude and uses wave lift to climb.  Likewise, you could put someone in a pressure suit aboard a Helios-like craft.  And then there's NASA's Mars helicopter: https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/

Comment: @jamesqf Thank you. I should have specified I rather meant subsonic jets, not gliders or propeller craft since these use in part other kinds of buoyancy. But I wonder whether a manned Helios-version wouldn't be too heavy for such high flight.

Comment: @jamesqf My question is about fixed-wing aircraft, not pure rotorcraft.

Comment: According to Wikipedia the U-2 has a service ceiling of 80,000 feet.

Comment: @MichaelHall I see, the U2 is subsonic. Thank you.

Comment: @EricS Yeah, also found that out just now by googling it ('ve been too busy before).

Comment: @Giovanni: Gliders & propellor airplanes do not use buoyancy.  Balloons use buoyancy. Per Wikipedia, the record for an unmanned balloon is 173K ft, manned a bit over 135K.  WRT the Mars helicopter, the point is that if a rotorcraft can work at such low atmospheric pressure, then prop planes should.  And WRT jets, I think at very high altitude you'd need either a rocket or an electric motor - but I defer to anyone with more knowledge.

Comment: @jamesqf Gliders do use buoyancy after they're released or what do you call it? I'd call gliding up a kind of buoyancy. But what I was referring to is something that keeps them from falling down (airflow).

Comment: @Giovanni: Buoyance is when an object weighs less than the material it's immersed in.  Balloons weigh less than the surrounding air, so they go up until they reach equilibrium. (Likewise ships displace an amount of water equal to their weight.)  Gliders climb by means of lift: they get into a bit of air that's rising, and climb along with it.  The lift can be from wind blowing up a slope (as with hang gliders on the coast), from thermals (most common with sailplanes), or mountain waves, which (as with the Perlan) can take you really high when conditions are right.

Comment: @Giovanni: To be clear, a glider is always going down relative to the surrounding air (ignoring maneuvers where you trade off speed & altitude: that's a net zero).  It's just that you can find masses of air that go up faster than the glider goes down.

Comment: It looks like the link is broken